# How to navigate JSON dataframe when level names vary?

Tags: r, json

I have get info about link from JSON file. It can be obtained with such code:

```
df$catalog$searchResultsV2$`searchResultsV2-193750`$items$link
```

But the problem in **19370**. This value can vary.

Is it possible to set route to *link*  dynamically (i can get this value)?

I tried to use paste() but in vain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to subset that part of the JSON as character name instead of `$`.

```
num <- 193750
df$catalog$searchResultsV2[[paste0("searchResultsV2-", num)]]$items$link
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but i get an error:


Error in df$catalog : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @ElvinFox can you then give a reproducible example using `dput(df)` ?

Comment: my bad, there were some more characters after the **19370** (removed it in the question to concentrate on the idea) , after i added it your solution worked just great, thanks!